# Read ADCP data in R

Tags: r

I have ADCP measured data for a river and I am wondering if it is possible to read the ADCP file in R. I found a package called "oce" but I couldn't read the ADCP file.

The function I found in oce package is as follows:

```
read.oce
read.adp
```

I have uploaded the sample file here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/owian354auah6h3/379D5spA2X.

If anyone could help me how to read this kind of ADCP, I would highly appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you mean by ADCP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_Doppler_Current_Profiler  In other words, are you trying to read a text file with unusual headers or maybe column formats that change after the first few lines?

Comment: @ Mark Yes, that is what I am trying to read. This text file is the output by the RDI Instrument.

Comment: There appear to be a lot of options: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/oce/docs/read.adp  You might have to tell people the definitions of the numbers in the first few rows of your data set.

Comment: DONT say "but I couldn't read the ADCP file". Tell us how you failed. Give us the R code you actually used, and the error message or other problem you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just a text file,  the simplest thing to do is to do something like

```
my_header <- readlines(myfile,n=7)
```

followed by

```
my_data <- read.table(myfile,skip=7,...)
```

(You'll need a few more parameters, probably, in those calls).

That way the metadata is separated from the array of data, which should simplify subsequent processing operations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party here, but hopefully, this will be useful for others.

```
data<-read.adp("my.prf", from = 1, to = 10, by=1, tz="UTC")
```

the arguments `from =` and `to =` correspond to the record number in the .sen file.